# Lyapunov function for nonlinear mass spring-damper system

Tags: matrices, control-theory, nonlinear-system

Consider the nonlinear model of a mass spring-damper:
$$
\begin{align}
\ddot{y} &= -2 \dot{y}\mid\dot{y}\mid - 5y -2y^3
\end{align}
$$
where y is the vertical displacement and mass is assumed unitary for simplicity.

By using the states: $$ \begin{align}
x_1 = y\\x_2 =\dot {y} 
\end{align}
$$
and equilibrium positions:
$$
\begin{align}
x_1 = 0 \\ x_2=0
\end{align}
$$
The matrix A of the linearised system around the equilibrium is found:
$$
\begin{align}
A= \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\ -5 &0\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
$$

A) How can I use the sum of the kinetic energy and potential energy stored in the spring tern as a Lyapunov function:
$$
\begin{align}
V(x_1,x_2) = \frac{1}{2}x_2^2 + \int_0^{x_1}({5z +2z^3})\,dz
\end{align}
$$
and prove global stability of the system?

B) Why can't this Lyapunov function be used to show global asymptotic stability of the system?

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Have you tried calculating $\dot{V}(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: I calculated the matrix A of the linearised system, but I am not sure how to proceed from there given this Lyapunov function.

Comment: In this case you don't really need $A$. Instead you can use $$\dot{V}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,x_1} \dot{x}_1 + \frac{\partial\,V}{\partial\,x_2} \dot{x}_2.$$